Chrome extension content script stops execution at first function call and does not throw errors
I made the first line of my content script a console.log(); statement because it appeared not to get loaded. The content script will run the first line, then does nothing else after that. No errors are thrown, none of the other console.log(); statements are processed, setting watch statements in Chrome DevTools Sources tab for the variables in the first function all are never set to any value; I'm at a loss for what is going on. I wrote the extension in vscode so it would tell me if I'd made any syntax errors, or something I was trying to do wasn't working, like the message passing to/from my background.service_worker. I'm not trying to import anything into the content script. I'm very much hoping the problem seems to be glaring to someone that reads my code so I can get some help. I am wasting too much time spinning wheels and not making any headway.
The extension is supposed to do two things—
One: search the text of the document.body of the DOM for matches of a set of regexes and replace any matches found with a hyperlink. The HTML code snippet is a test file that should have most of the text after the bullet points hyperlinked.
Two: add a context menu entry that shows up when selected text is right-clicked that allows the user to jump to a ServiceNow form or run a ServiceNow search.
The context menu functionality works without any problem, and like I said there are no errors thrown that I've found during my testing so far, so the background.service_worker code is solid and the imports have to all be correct and working right, too. The issue must be with the content script.
manifest.json
{
  "name": "SearchNow",
  "description": "Search ServiceNow",
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "version": "0.9",
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "background-simplified.js",
    "type": "module"
  },
  "icons": {
    "16": "icons/SNow16.png",
    "24": "icons/SNow24.png",
    "32": "icons/SNow32.png",
    "48": "icons/SNow48.png",
    "128": "icons/SNow128.png"
  },
  "action": {
    "default_icon": {
      "16": "icons/SNow16.png",
      "24": "icons/SNow24.png",
      "32": "icons/SNow32.png"
    },
    "default_title": "Click for advanced search options",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["http://*/*", "https://*/*", "file:///*/*"],
      "css": ["styles.css"],
      "js": ["content-script-hyperlinker.js"],
      "run_at": "document_end"
    }
  ],
  "options_ui": {
    "page": "options.html",
    "open_in_tab": true
  },
  "permissions": [
    "activeTab",
    "alarms",
    "tabs",
    "scripting",
    "storage",
    "contextMenus"
  ],
  "host_permissions": [
    "<all_urls>"
  ],
  "commands": {
    "autoSearch": {
      "suggested_key": {
        "default": "Ctrl+Shift+1"
      },
      "description": "AutoSearch selected text"
    },
    "autoNav": {
      "suggested_key": {
        "default": "Ctrl+Shift+2"
      },
      "description": "Automatically navigate to selected record"
    }
  }
}

content-script-hyperlinker.js

console.log('Content script loaded.');

runner();

function hyperlinkMatches(node, regexPatterns) {
    if (node.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE) {
        let text = node.nodeValue;
        let replacedText = text;

        console.log('Original text:', text);

        for (const [patternName, regex] of Object.entries(regexPatterns)) {
            replacedText = replacedText.replace(new RegExp(regex), (match) => {
                chrome.runtime.sendMessage(
                    {
                        action: 'constructUrl',
                        base: 'https://gsa.servicenowservices.com',
                        path: '/nav_to.do',
                        query: match
                    },
                    (response) => {
                        const url = response.url;
                        console.log(`Match found: ${match}, URL: ${url}`);
                        return `<a href="${url}" target="_blank">${match}</a>`;
                    }
                );
            });
        }

        if (replacedText !== text) {
            console.log('Replaced text:', replacedText);
            const span = document.createElement('span');
            span.innerHTML = replacedText;
            node.parentNode.replaceChild(span, node);
        }
    } else if (node.nodeType === Node.ELEMENT_NODE && node.nodeName !== 'SCRIPT' && node.nodeName !== 'STYLE') {
        for (let child = node.firstChild; child; child = child.nextSibling) {
            hyperlinkMatches(child, regexPatterns);
        }
    }
}

function runner () {
    console.log('Document loaded, starting hyperlinking process.');
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ action: 'getRegexPatterns' }, (response) => {
        const regexPatterns = response.regexPatterns;
        hyperlinkMatches(document.body, regexPatterns);
    });
}

// document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', runner);

background-simplified.js
import { autoNav } from './handlers/autoNav.js';
import { autoSearch } from './handlers/autoSearch.js';
import { constructUrl } from './utils/urlConstructor.js';
import * as eventListeners from './eventListeners.js';
import * as regexPatterns from './utils/regexPatterns.js';

/* jshint esversion: 6*/

// Initialize event listeners
eventListeners.setupEventListeners();

// Create context menu entries
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(() => {
    chrome.contextMenus.create({
        id: 'autoNav',
        title: 'Open "%s"',
        contexts: ['selection']
    });

    chrome.contextMenus.create({
        id: 'autoSearch',
        title: 'Search ServiceNow for "%s"',
        contexts: ['selection']
    });
});

// Handle message passing with content script
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((request, sender, sendResponse) => {
    if (request.action === 'getRegexPatterns') {
        sendResponse({ regexPatterns });
    } else if (request.action === 'constructUrl') {
        const url = constructUrl(request.base, request.path, request.query);
        sendResponse({ url });
    }
});

// Handle context menu item clicks
chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener((info, tab) => {
    if (info.menuItemId === 'autoNav') {
        autoNav(info, tab);
    } else if (info.menuItemId === 'autoSearch') {
        autoSearch(info, tab);
    }
});



<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Test Page for Content Script</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Test Page for Content Script</h1>
    <p>Here are some test cases for the regex patterns:</p>
    <ul>
        <li>KB1234567</li>
        <li>INC1234567</li>
        <li>RITM1234567</li>
        <li>STASK1234567</li>
        <li>REQ1234567</li>
        <li>CALL1234567</li>
        <li>PRB1234567</li>
        <li>CHG1234567</li>
        <li>SEC1234567</li>
        <li>CHAT1234567</li>
        <li>192.168.1.1</li>
        <li>example@example.com</li>
        <li>CO0102A-12345678</li>
        <li>(123) 456-7890</li>
        <li>AB123456789</li>
    </ul>
</body>
</html>




Remove DOMContentLoaded and just call runner() directly because your script already runs after that event has been fired.

@woxxom First, thank you for the suggestion. I tried calling runner() directly and commenting out the DOMContentLoaded event listener, but I'm getting the same results. I'm updating the code to reflect the changes I made.

Debug it in devtools. Set a breakpoint on the first line then execute the script line by line (F10 or F11 keys).

Please check the tagging of your post and remove those tags that are not relevant. To me, CSS and JSON look unrelated to the problem. Also, what have you tried to resolve the problem?

I try to copy and paste all the file you provided and comment some part of the code, so the extension can be loaded by the chrome browser.
As shown in the following figure, the console.log are successfully processed, tho it doesn't return the actual replacedText because you don't provide the file.
Edit: FYI, I am using Chrome version 131.0.6778.109 (Official Build) (64-bit)

// manifest.json
{
  "name": "SearchNow",
  "description": "Search ServiceNow",
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "version": "0.9",
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "background-simplified.js",
    "type": "module"
  },
  // "icons": {
  //   "16": "icons/SNow16.png",
  //   "24": "icons/SNow24.png",
  //   "32": "icons/SNow32.png",
  //   "48": "icons/SNow48.png",
  //   "128": "icons/SNow128.png"
  // },
  // "action": {
  //   "default_icon": {
  //     "16": "icons/SNow16.png",
  //     "24": "icons/SNow24.png",
  //     "32": "icons/SNow32.png"
  //   },
  //   "default_title": "Click for advanced search options",
  //   "default_popup": "popup.html"
  // },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": [
        "http://*/*",
        "https://*/*",
        "file:///*/*"
      ],
      // "css": [
      //   "styles.css"
      // ],
      "js": [
        "content-script-hyperlinker.js"
      ],
      "run_at": "document_end"
    }
  ],
  // "options_ui": {
  //   "page": "options.html",
  //   "open_in_tab": true
  // },
  "permissions": [
    "activeTab",
    "alarms",
    "tabs",
    "scripting",
    "storage",
    "contextMenus"
  ],
  "host_permissions": [
    "<all_urls>"
  ],
  "commands": {
    "autoSearch": {
      "suggested_key": {
        "default": "Ctrl+Shift+1"
      },
      "description": "AutoSearch selected text"
    },
    "autoNav": {
      "suggested_key": {
        "default": "Ctrl+Shift+2"
      },
      "description": "Automatically navigate to selected record"
    }
  }
}

// background-simplified.js

// import { autoNav } from './handlers/autoNav.js';
// import { autoSearch } from './handlers/autoSearch.js';
// import { constructUrl } from './utils/urlConstructor.js';
// import * as eventListeners from './eventListeners.js';
// import * as regexPatterns from './utils/regexPatterns.js';

/* jshint esversion: 6*/

// Initialize event listeners
// eventListeners.setupEventListeners();

// Create context menu entries
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(() => {
  chrome.contextMenus.create({
    id: 'autoNav',
    title: 'Open "%s"',
    contexts: ['selection']
  });

  chrome.contextMenus.create({
    id: 'autoSearch',
    title: 'Search ServiceNow for "%s"',
    contexts: ['selection']
  });
});

// Handle message passing with content script
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((request, sender, sendResponse) => {
  if (request.action === 'getRegexPatterns') {
    sendResponse({ regexPatterns: '' });
  } else if (request.action === 'constructUrl') {
    // const url = constructUrl(request.base, request.path, request.query);
    sendResponse({ url: '' });
  }
});

// Handle context menu item clicks
chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener((info, tab) => {
  // if (info.menuItemId === 'autoNav') {
  //   autoNav(info, tab);
  // } else if (info.menuItemId === 'autoSearch') {
  //   autoSearch(info, tab);
  // }
  console.log('contextMenus')
});


// content-script-hyperlinker.js

console.log('Content script loaded.');

runner();

function hyperlinkMatches(node, regexPatterns) {
  if (node.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE) {
    let text = node.nodeValue;
    let replacedText = text;

    console.log('Original text:', text);

    for (const [patternName, regex] of Object.entries(regexPatterns)) {
      replacedText = replacedText.replace(new RegExp(regex), (match) => {
        chrome.runtime.sendMessage(
          {
            action: 'constructUrl',
            base: 'https://gsa.servicenowservices.com',
            path: '/nav_to.do',
            query: match
          },
          (response) => {
            const url = response.url;
            console.log(`Match found: ${match}, URL: ${url}`);
            return `<a href="${url}" target="_blank">${match}</a>`;
          }
        );
      });
    }

    console.log('Replaced text:', replacedText);
    if (replacedText !== text) {
      console.log('Replaced text:', replacedText);
      const span = document.createElement('span');
      span.innerHTML = replacedText;
      node.parentNode.replaceChild(span, node);
    }
  } else if (node.nodeType === Node.ELEMENT_NODE && node.nodeName !== 'SCRIPT' && node.nodeName !== 'STYLE') {
    for (let child = node.firstChild; child; child = child.nextSibling) {
      hyperlinkMatches(child, regexPatterns);
    }
  }
}

function runner() {
  console.log('Document loaded, starting hyperlinking process.');
  chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ action: 'getRegexPatterns' }, (response) => {
    const regexPatterns = response.regexPatterns;
    hyperlinkMatches(document.body, regexPatterns);
  });
}





"...and did some editing" - what did you change, and why? Keep in mind that a good explanation helps others to learn from your answer

@NicoHaase I provided all the code and things that I changed. It's just I commented out some things that can't be used. For example, on import /something.js. Edited my answer

Did you change anything that actually solves the OP's problem? If not, this shouldn't be posted as an answer. If you did, explain what the problem was and how you fixed it.

Yeah I was going to post this as a comment but I can't do it (not enough reputation) @Barmar. But what I am basically explaining is that: I cannot recreate the problem on my machine
